# Lightbox System w/ SQL

Tags: php, lightbox, photo-gallery

I'm currently building a small PHP photo gallery system using lightbox. 
My code:

```html
<div class="col-7 offset-2 p-2">
  <a href="uploads/entrance.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery"><img src="uploads/entrance.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <?php foreach ($photos as $photo){?>
              <a  class="gone" href="<?php echo $photo->file_path('uploads',$photo->filename)?>" data-  lightbox="gallery"><img src="<?php echo $photo->file_path('uploads',$photo->filename)?>" alt=""></a>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I wish to show the first indexed/id photo as the thumbnail/cover image. Once the user wishes to view the gallery, they can click the image and lightbox launches allowing a preview of the photos drawn from SQL.

How do I achieve this?

This may be quite an amateur question, but I'm meddling around with what I've learnt from youtube :P

Comment: You'll need to build a custom ajax handler that you'll call when the user opens up lightbox. That handler would then go to a PHP class that handles the SQL and returns the data you need.

Comment: You could create links for all your images, but make visible only the first one. See the last example here - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/mqEMGX?editors=1000